# Leaderboard ads now appearing

Tags: support, advertising

I don't know if this is a bug or a revocation of a privilege or a new approach to advertising, but I am now seeing "leaderboard" ads on SO when previously I was not (I have sufficient reputation for the "Reduce Ads" privilege).

By "leaderboard" I mean the definition given in the "Reduce Ads" privilege - just below the "Stackoverlow" banner for both the main list and in questions.

Here's a screenshot: [image: screenshot of ads]

Comment: What are "leaderboard" ads? What exactly are you seeing? Screenshots help.

Comment: @Oded screenshot added

Comment: Nope, not ours. Looks like you got some toolbar / adware there. Could be injected by your ISP?

Comment: Could be, but I'm using Chrome and I can't see anything in my tools etc.

Comment: Hover over that `i` icon under the ad, next to "Ads Not by This Site" - may tell you what's going on.

Comment: http://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-ads-not-by-this-site/

Comment: Firebug shows the ads are form http://servedby.adsdumpo.com - stay tuned

Comment: Super User to the rescue? [“Ads not by this site” displayed by ads injected into certain web pages](http://superuser.com/questions/408224/ads-not-by-this-site-displayed-by-ads-injected-into-certain-web-pages).

Comment: OK I am *only* getting this for stackoverflow. No other websites have this banner!

Comment: @Oded Turned out to be a Chrome extension called "Hosts". Don't know how it got there. Nuking it fixed the problem.

Comment: GR8 - nothing like your friendly adware to ruin the user experience

Comment: They are remarkably well targeted and placed.  Somebody knows exactly what the SO front page looks like and who visits the site.

Answer (score 16):

Those are not our ads. We've seen this before and it turned out to be a rogue addon inserting ads into the page. Try disabling all plugins / addons and see if it goes away. If not, you may be infected with some adware.

Comment: It actually says below the ad: *Ads Not by This Site*

Comment: @Stijn - a clue! (well spotted)

Comment: Or a really obnoxious ISP that injects ads to their clients.

Comment: @Stijn doh! Quite so: Malware. See my answer for what it was.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Chrome. The issue was an extension called "Hosts" - nuking it fixed the problem.
I have no idea how it came to be installed.

Note that a cursory use of other sites did *not* show this problem - it must target certain types of sites only.

Comment: It was installed as result of a virus or legit software that silently added it as well. See here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/W1ThgbhLPA4

Comment: You posted the comment on the wrong answer. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No. Deliberate. stijn noticed the "ads not from this site" on the other answer, and I wanted to bring his attention to this answer to show him what the malware was exactlyq

Comment: @Bohemian - If only `@` on comments worked like that. Stijn won't be notified as there is no comment by him/her on _this_ answer.

Comment: @Oded thx. I should know that :/ I've never tried cross-notifying before.

Comment: Do you know of any other plugins that use this? Can you tell me the install path of this plugin? on our firewall their ad pages are one of our mos hit sites, i think we have an infestation

Comment: @acme64 my infection was in the client browser and I fixed it by uninstalling it via the browser. Sorry, I don't know the install path or of other similar plugins.